# Will adding @ManyToOne cause to extra query over the referenced table?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

If I use @ManyToOne with fetch type LAZY or any other jpa mapping annotations, will jpa run a query on the mapped entity to fetch the id?

For example.

Department

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    // Constructors, getters, setters, and other properties
}
```

Employee:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Department department;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, and other properties
}
```

Now let's say when I try find by on Employee and try to get id from the department corresponding to the employee, will Hibernate release an extra query to the Department class and fetch id from the department where employee = 'x'. Or will the department id be stored with the employee entity and I can fetch it without increasing my query time? since the department id is present in the employee table in mysql?

```
Employee emp = employeeRepository.findByName("John");
String deparmentId = emp.getDeparment().getId(); //Extra query time or not? As Id is stored in the mysql table
emp.getDepartment().getName(); //Does causes extra query
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are querying with Spring JPA, you are given the **instance** of the data object(s) that represents the returned query value. This *includes relational data* as long as you have the proper annotations (which you do).

JPA is mapping your database tables to an instance of your Entity. Any fields (via getter/setter) will be accessible to you immediately after you retrieve that Entity instance from a query (`findBy`, etc).

So, for example. If you query for a single Department like so:

```
Optional<Department> aDepartmentOpt = departmentRepository.findById(2);

// assume we checked aDepartmentOpt for isEmpty()
Department department = aDepartmentOpt.get();

// lets get its employees
List<Employee> dptEmployees = department.getEmployees();

// do stuff with it... we have access to its data already
for(Employee e : dptEmployees) {
    System.out.println("Employee " + e.getId() + " - " + e.getName());
}
```

And vice-versa:

```
Optional<Employee> employeeOpt = employeeRepository.findById(2);

// assume we checked employeeOpt for isEmpty()
Employee employee = employeeOpt.get();

// lets get the employees department
Department department = employee.getDepartment();

// do stuff with it... we dont need to query the department cause we have its data right here:
System.out.println("Department " + department.getId() + " - " + department.getName());
```

Note that when you use `mappedBy`, you are giving Spring JPA the field name so it can associate that with the instance of the data object for when you query.

Hope this helped.

Comment: No that’s not how jpa works, the default fetch type is lazy and as long as I don’t call the get methods present in the department table it should only be returning the proxy of the department table. What I want to know is, will it query over the department table even to fetch the referencedColumn? Which is department id in this case as the department id should be present in the employee table as foreign key?

Comment: The default fetch type is EAGER, actually. Which will do exactly as shown in the example above. Reference from an article on it: "In eager loading strategy, if we load the User data, it will also load up all orders associated with it and will store it in a memory." source: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading

Comment: Thanks! My bad. For one to many it is lazy but for many to one it is eager. I should have formulated the question well, in case of lazy loading will it query over the db even if I need to fetch the id? Which has already been mapped in the database?

Comment: To my understanding, Eager loads it immediately on first object fetch. So any corresponding relations (i.e. a Department's list of Students or a Student's Department) is fetched immediately. Lazy will do it the moment its needed, so it will fetch only when you actually ask for the relation data (list of Students for a Department) in that moment. So that would mean "yes" to your question (if you mean fetch ID of the Student's Department, or vice versa). It's better than manually querying for the ID yourself imo cause it does the same thing.

Comment: The id of the department is already stored in the employee table in the database. then querying it again to fetch the id would be redundant. If that's the case then wouldn't it be better to handle the relationship in the service layer and just store the id in the database without any reference?

Comment: I thought you meant getting the ID(s) of other side of the relationship. Not really sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

yes, calling getDepartment() is expected to force a fetch to the database on lazy relationships. This is implementation (and configuration) specific on if the getDepartment() call immediately fetches from the database or if you get a proxy object that calling anything on then fetches from the DB, so I wouldn't rely on it. If you want to have access to the FK value ("department_id") when only fetching the Employee instance without knowing if the department has already been fetched, map it as a basic Long property in the entity directly. You can have multiple mappings to the same "department_id" as long as you specify only one as writable (so all others as updatable=false, insertable=false).  Ie

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "department_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long departmentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    private Department department;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, and other properties
}
```

This allows you to continue to use and reference department in queries to perform joins, but can allow you to use departmentId directly to avoid them. Ie:

```
  "select employee from Employee employee where employee.department.id =:deptId"
```

vs

```
  "select employee from Employee employee where employee.departmentId = :deptId"
```

The first query should force an inner join to the department, while the second doesn't.

Depending on your application requirements, you can also reverse which property sets the "department_id" column value so that it can be set via the departmentId - this can be useful where you may want to merge in employees via REST without having to build back Department objects and handle reading and merging them in too - only the departmentId long is required for serialization.